# What does WindowsXP SetMonTime.exe command do?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, sp3, powercfg

I noticed on my Windows XP SP3 workstation a command runs at startup as follows:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\SetMonTime 600
```

I searched on the net and there is absolutely no reference to what it is and what it does.
All I know it there is a inf file attached:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dir /b SetMonTime.*
SetMonTime.exe
SetMonTime.inf
```

with the following content:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>type SetMonTime.inf
[Unicode]
Unicode=yes
[Registry Values]
[Version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
Revision=1
[Registry Keys]
"MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Controls Folder\PowerCfg",0,"
D:AR(A;CI;KA;;;AU)"
[Privilege Rights]
SeShutdownPrivilege = *S-1-5-11
```

So, what is the purpose of SetMonTime.exe ?

Comment: A wild guess: set monitor timeout to 600 seconds (i.e. 10 minutes)? It's not a built-in executable, anyway. Can you upload it somewhere and post here link, or at least provide more details about the file (size, version, description, hashes, etc.)?

Comment: @and31415 It turns out you were correct it is an app designed to set the monitor timeout (in seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after I checked the "Properties" page

> - Description: Sets monitor timeout in seconds of active power
> - Company: Enterprise Automation Ltd

Comment: You should probably go ahead and accept your own answer if this was the information you were looking for.